# Docusign integration with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, docusignapi

I am using the [docusign_rest](https://github.com/jondkinney/docusign_rest) gem for DocuSign REST API, and following are my DocuSign configuration.

```
# config/initializers/docusign_rest.rb

require 'docusign_rest'
DocusignRest.configure do |config|
  config.username       = 'myemail@email.com'
  config.password       = 'MyPassword'
  config.integrator_key = 'My-key'
  config.account_id     = 'account_id'
  config.endpoint      = 'https://www.docusign.net/restapi'
  config.api_version   = 'v1'
end
```

When I try to connect and get account_id, I get `nil` as a response.

```
client = DocusignRest::Client.new
puts client.get_account_id         # Returns nil.
```

I am using `rails-4.1.4` and `ruby-2.2.2`

What did I miss? Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried `config.api_version  = 'v2'` ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you figured this out or not quite yet. Here is another solution that wasn't too difficult using httparty. If you're trying to create a document for a template for example, your request might look like so:

```
baseUrl = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/acct_number/envelopes"
    @lease = Lease.find(lease.id)
    @unit = @lease.unit
    @application = @lease.application
    @manager = @lease.property_manager

    @application.applicants.each do |renter|
    req = HTTParty.post(baseUrl,
        body:  {
            "emailSubject": "DocuSign API call - Request Signature - Boom",
            "templateId": "id of your template",
            "templateRoles": [{
                "name": "#{renter.background.legal_name}",
                "email": "#{renter.email}",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "roleName": "Lessee",
                "tabs": {
                    "texttabs": [{
                                "tablabel": "Rent",
                                "value": "#{@lease.rent}"
                                },{
                                "tablabel": "Address",
                                "value": "987 apple lane"
                        }]
                    }
                },{
                "email": "#{@manager.email}",
                "name": "#{@manager.name}",
                "roleName": "Lessor",
                "tabs": {
                    "texttabs": [{
                                "tablabel": "Any",
                                "value": "#{@lease.labels}"
                                },{
                                "tablabel": "Address",
                                "value": "987 hoser lane"
                    }]
                }
            }],
            "status": "sent"
        }.to_json,
        headers: {
            "Content-Type" => "application/json",
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'X-DocuSign-Authentication' => '{
            "Username" : "place your",
            "Password" : "credentials",
            "IntegratorKey" : "here"
            }'
        }, :debug_output => $stdout )
```

debug output on the final line is to allow you to debug the api request, it can be removed at any time.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in docusign_rest 0.1.1; that method always returned `nil`.  That bug has been [fixed](https://github.com/jondkinney/docusign_rest/commit/d9a00d853f8173132dc84368cd8cd3f2089b8fb8) and the latest gem version includes that fix.